# How to create new columns of last 5 sale price off in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of sneakers sale, which looks like this,
[image]

I added columns last1, ..., last5 indicating the last 5 sale prices of the sneakers and made them all None. I'm trying to update the values of these new columns using the 'Sale Price' column. This is my attempt to do so,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (index==0):
        continue
    for i in range(index-1, -1, -1):
        if df['Sneaker Name'][index] == df['Sneaker Name'][i]:
            df['last5'][index] = df['last4'][i]
            df['last4'][index] = df['last3'][i]
            df['last3'][index] = df['last2'][i]
            df['last2'][index] = df['last1'][i]
            df['last1'][index] = df['Sale Price'][i]
            continue
    if (index == 100):
        break
```

When I ran this, I got a warning,
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

and the result is also wrong.
Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Also, this is the expected output,
[image]

Comment: kindly share reproducible dataframe with expected output

Comment: When you use index like `df['last5'][index]`, the variable is a slice copy of that DataFrame. Hence, setting a value to that new slice will result in the warning.

Try this instead of the for loop, if you have all rows sorted :
```python
df['last1'] = df['Sale Price'].shift(1)
df['last2'] = df['last1'].shift(1)
df['last3'] = df['last2'].shift(1)
df['last4'] = df['last3'].shift(1)
df['last5'] = df['last4'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of for loop, if you have rows sorted:

```py
df['last1'] = df['Sale Price'].shift(1)
df['last2'] = df['last1'].shift(1)
df['last3'] = df['last2'].shift(1)
df['last4'] = df['last3'].shift(1)
df['last5'] = df['last4'].shift(1)
```